# Flutter responsiveness problem on various mobile devices

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am a beginner to Flutter and I tried creating a dummy login page. When I tried to run the app it was flawless on Pixel 3 XL but it was not good in Pixel 2 XL. How would I manage the responsiveness? I came across the `MediaQuery` widget, but how could I create a completely responsive app for each device? There are many variations among today's mobile devices (like notched display, fullscreen, etc) and thereafter comes the tablets. How could I manage this? Should I write code for each and every resolution?

**Here is my design on Pixel 3 XL and Pixel 2 XL**

[image: running on pixel 3 XL]

[image: running on pixel 2 XL]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind this problem is the sizedbox widget with height 100px.
removing that and using mainaxisalignment as spaceevenly gives the required output.
Here is the modified code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          bgimage,
         Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                logoimage,    
                userName(),    
                password(),
                forgotPassword(),    
                loginButton(),
                googleSignIn(),
                signUp()
              ],
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SingleChildScrollView` as parent,

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Stack(
        ),
      ),
    );
```

---

Edit: Also remove `fit: StackFit.expand,` from `Stack` widget.

Comment: I tried that but it did not change anything...take a look at my code and make suggestions if possible https://codeshare.io/GqVWrx

Comment: create a git repo of your complete code, I will look into it

Comment: here is my repo: https://github.com/bala0406/focus7     I pushed the master so the changes you said will not be available.

Comment: although I could not able to run your project but removing `fit: StackFit.expand,` from `Stack` must help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried removing the fit property, but still, the problem persists

Answer (score 2):

Best easiest way to make responsive UI for different screen size is [Sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) plugin.
[image: a busy cat]

Responsive UI in any screen size device also tablet.
Check it this plugin ⬇️
https://pub.dev/packages/sizer

```
.h  - for widget height
.w  - for widget width
.sp - for font size
```

Use `.h`, `.w`, `.sp` after value like this ⬇️

Example:

```
Container(
  height: 10.0.h,  //10% of screen height
  width: 80.0.w,   //80% of screen width
  child: Text('Sizer', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0.sp)),
);
```

**I have build many responsive UI with this plugin.**

Answer (score 0):

Use this package [flutter_next](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_next) using this you design responsive UI even for desktop web and everything and they have an demo also so you can check there